# Trying to verify saddle surface is a minimal surface

Tags: calculus-of-variations, minimal-surfaces

I am reading a book on calculus of variation, and it talks about minimal surface, it gives the equation of minimal surface of $z(x,y)$, it should satisfy:

$$(1 + z_y^2)z_{xx} - 2 z_x z_y z_{xy} + (1+z_x^2)z_{yy} = 0$$

and then says the saddle surface:

$$z = x^3 - 2xy^2$$

can easily verify that this equation satisfy the above equation.

But I cann't verify it, here's my calculation process:

$$z_x = 3x^2 - 2y^2 $$

$$z_y = -4xy $$

$$z_{xx} = 6x$$

$$z_{yy} = -4x$$

$$z_{xy} = -4y $$

$$z_{yx} = -4y$$

Then plug into the above equation:

$$(1 + z_y^2)z_{xx} - 2 z_x z_y z_{xy} + (1+z_x^2)z_{yy} $$

$$ = \big( 1 + (-4xy)^2 \big) 6x  - 2 (3x^2 - 2y^2)( -4xy)(-4y) + \big( 1 + (3x^2 - 2y^2)^2 \big) (-4x) $$

$$ = \big( 1 + 16x^2y^2 \big) 6x  - 2 (3x^2 - 2y^2)(4xy)(4y) - \big( 1 + (3x^2 - 2y^2)^2 \big) 4x$$

$$= 6x + 96x^3y^2 - 32xy^2(3x^2 - 2y^2) - 4x \big( 1 + 9x^4 + 4y^4 - 12x^2y^2 \big) $$

$$ = 6x + 96x^3y^2 - 96x^3y^2 + 64xy^4 - 4x - 36x^5  - 16xy^4 + 48 x^3y^2 $$

$$ =  2x + 64xy^4 -  36x^5  - 16xy^4 + 48 x^3y^2 $$

$$ = -36x^5 + 48 x^3y^2 + 48xy^4 + 2x $$

I can't tell that $-36x^5 + 48 x^3y^2 + 48xy^4 + 2x = 0$, is there any wrong with the calculation?

===========
update, thanks for the comments.

it turns out the book have a typo on this equation, it should be

$$z = x^3 - 3xy^2$$

and it is called [Monkey saddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle). And this is still not a minimal surface.

Comment: something is wrong, if $z = x^3 -2x y^2$  means the graph of a function:  this can't be a minimal surface. However, given a minimal surface $z=f(x,y)$   which is horizontal at the origin,   then the Laplacian of $f$ really is zero at the origin, but just at the single point.  What book are you talking about?

Comment: The book is <Applied Calculus of Variations for Engineers>, omg, thanks for the comments, I just googled and found out the surface should be $z = x^3 - 3xy^2$, then the book do have a typo here, $z = x^3 - 3xy^2$ is called monkey saddle according to wikipedia.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_saddle

Comment: Well, $x^3 - 3 x y^2$ is harmonic, it is the real part of $(x+iy)^3.$   However, its graph is still not a minimal surface.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, this is still not a minimal surface since I still cannot get the result verified after tried. It seems this book needs an errata.